# DAX - SUMMARIZE based on SWITCH statement

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have SKUs data with some financial information. I have grouped the SKUs in 4 categories using a measure with SWITCH. Now I would like to summarise the information (e.g. total revenues of the products in each category) but I cannot get the summary to add up to the correct value.

**Data model:**

- FactTable: fact table containing financial information (product code, revenue, profit, period, etc.)
- DimSKU: mapping table with SKUs data (product code, brand, segment, etc.)
- DimDates: date table (period, months, etc.)

**Creating 4 product categories:**
*(using a measure and not a calculated column as the users can use a dropdown list and select different periods)*

```
My Quadrants =
VAR
    Quadrants =
    SWITCH(
        TRUE(),
        AND([SKU_profit] >= [Total_profit], [SKU_growth] >= [Total_growth]), "Maintain",
        AND([SKU_profit] <  [Total_profit], [SKU_growth] <  [Total_growth]), "Address",
        AND([SKU_profit] >= [Total_profit], [SKU_growth] <  [Total_growth]), "Grow",
        AND([SKU_profit] <  [Total_profit], [SKU_growth] >= [Total_growth]), "Investigate"
    )
RETURN
    Quadrants
```

**Calculating YTD sales:**

```
YTD revenue =
VAR
    YTD_revenue = TOTALYTD(SUM(FactTable[Revenue]), DimDates[Date])
RETURN
    YTD_revenue
```

**Summarising data:**

I can add the measure to a visual like a table and it works perfectly fine as long as I also display all the SKUs. Ideally, I would like a summary like the following:

```
MyQuadrants / Revenue
Maintain / 1,000
Address / 250
Grow / 500
Investigate / 350
```

I would be grateful if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks all.

---

### **Edit**

I have managed to make it work thanks to David's suggestion. See below for reference.

**Creating configuration table**

```
ConfigTable =
VAR
    Total_profit = [Total_profit]
VAR
    Total_growth = [Total_growth]
RETURN
    {
        ("Maintain", Total_profit, 1, Total_growth, 1),
        ("Address", 0, Total_profit, 0, Total_growth),
        ("Grow", Total_profit, 1, 0, Total_growth),
        ("Investigate", 0, Total_profit, Total_growth, 1)
    }

// 5 columns: quadrant, min profit, max profit, min growth, max growth
// Use table constructor to use variables
```

**Creating measure**

```
YTD revenue (segmented) =
CALCULATE(
    [YTD revenue],
    FILTER(
        VALUES(DimSKU),
        NOT ISEMPTY(
                FILTER(
                    ConfigTable,
                    (
                    [SKU_profit] >= ConfigTable[min profit] &&
                    [SKU_profit] <  ConfigTable[max profit] &&
                    [SKU_growth] >= ConfigTable[min growth] &&
                    [SKU_growth] <  ConfigTable[min growth]
                    )
                )
     )
)
```

Comment: This is dynamic segmentation. Have a read here: https://www.daxpatterns.com/dynamic-segmentation/

Comment: Measure "YTD sales" is incorrect. After you store a calculation in a variable (Total_Revenue), it becomes static, and can not be recalculated in the CALCULATE function.

Comment: @David: thanks, I'm a bit struggling to implement "dynamic segmentation" but will spend more time looking into it.